# Non-linear behavior of the transistor and many other questions got me desperate. Help me design a class A amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, small-signal, bypass-capacitor

Firstly, no. This is not an assignment. Indeed I passed the Electronics class with a high mark last year. Out of curiosity, I decided to design a class A amplifier with a 2N3904 transistor, because I recently bought a oscilloscope and wanted to play with it a little. My project was going to be a Common-Emitter Amplifier (let's say for an AM radio):

[image: Schematic]

Here Vout channel also has a filter capacitor, just like Vin. I selected both 20nF as I saw in an example circuit. *Meanwhile, the bypass capacitor C2 was selected 1uF because we need a low impedance in the emitter channel to maximize the gain*. AC signal will flow through the capacitor without a loss. [Wrong: It is not there to reduce the impedance. This would distort the signal.]

1. Why don't we attach a parallel bypass capacitor to the collector channel as well? Wouldn't this help us? [Solved: it would short-circuit the Vout]
2. Why do we want to keep the input and the output impedances high? 20nF will produce a much bigger reactance than 1uF. [Solved: Indeed, my guess below is correct.]
3. I tend to think it is about the frequency of the signals we want to amplify. In the case of AM radio signals, we will deal with a scale of 100 kHz. Capacitance can be set accordingly so that lower frequencies will get filtered to produce a cleaner result. If this is indeed the case, what would be the formula to determine the required capacitance for a chosen cutoff frequency? Moreover, how to choose the cutoff frequency? [Solved: Here AC analysis comes into the game. The emitter bypass capacitor can be designed without it with regards to the emitter resistor but for the input and the output channels, we need to know the input and the output impedances of the circuit.]

**Now let's come into the logic behind this system.**

I noticed that as we reduce Re, the output signal gets more distorted. Re functions as reverse feedback. Ib gets higher (because of the signal), more Ic is drawn from the source, and a higher voltage falls on the Re, hence Ve increases to limit the base current, and vice versa. Eventually, it stabilizes the system.

4. The gain is also dependent on -Rc/Re. For a higher gain, we need a low Re but a Re which is too low will just ruin our signal. How to do a trade-off? [Solved: Keep Ic small and resistor values big.]

Ic, Rc, and Re should be set so carefully that Vc will be Vcc/2, in my case 12 / 2 = 6 volts. This is called the offset voltage. The signal will be amplified on this axis. A too-low or a too-high offset voltage will get our signal cropped.

5. Then Vce + Ie **x** Re = 6 volts. Here the second term should leave space for the Vce; Transistor should never get fully saturated. This is because Vce needs space to fall when a negative output signal is getting produced. There Ic, consequently V.Rc and V.Re, rise to squeeze the Vce. But I don't know how to choose the optimal Vce. Here I think that Vout should fit between +6 (positive alternance) and -Vce (negative alternance) volts. Just like the scale of Vin, the gain rate also affects Vout, so I failed to solve this problem. [Solved: we want to keep Re small compared to Rc for a greater gain rate. For this, we should keep Vce as high as possible. Conventional wisdom is that 1 Volt should fall on the emitter resistor.]

(Such an ideal pair of Ic and Vce is called the Q-point. What we do here is called transistor biasing.)

6. Once the required Vce (and then Ic) is determined, together with the gain rate, resistor values can be easily calculated. But now the problem here is the non-linear behavior of our transistor. Unlike the heavenly predictable theory, down-to-ground practice is unpredictable and non-linear. First of all, hfe is not a constant but it depends on Ic and also temperature. Here we assume the transistor won't get hot at all and will operate at 25°C.

[image: Graph]

Looking at the datasheet for 2N3904, we find this graph here. How are we supposed to pick the best pair of hfe and Ic? (What does the "Vce=1V" even mean there?) [Solved: Current should be kept fairly small, and resistor values should be big. What we want is voltage amplification. Current amplification can be done afterward. We are not interested in power at this point. On Vce=1.0V, it is about the Early effect. The current gain is **also** dependent on the Vce but it doesn't make a great difference, to be honest.]

[Addition: We usually want a current of 10 times the Ib to pass through the resistors R1 and R2. This is the key design principle.]

I am stuck folks, please illuminate me. I have been non-stop trying to understand what is going on for 2-3 days. I didn't expect such a seemingly simple circuit to have that many crucial nuances.

[Here is the datasheet for our transistor.](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n3903-d.pdf)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145915/discussion-on-question-by-brahim-pek-non-linear-behavior-of-the-transistor-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.